# Seeking to a Kafka Offset with Spring Cloud Stream

Tags: java, spring-cloud-stream, spring-kafka

I have an event-sourced service that listens to a Kafka topic and saves state in a relational DB.

Considering a suitable restoration strategy for this service (i.e. how to restore the DB in a disaster recovery scenario), one option would be to save the current offset in the DB, take snapshots, and restore from a snapshot. In this scenario the service would need to seek to the offset when started in 'restoration mode'.

I am using Spring Cloud Stream, and was wondering if the framework provides any mechanism for seeking to an offset?

*I realise another option for restoration would be to simply play all the events from scratch, but that's not an ideal option for some of my microservices.*

Answer (score 2):

There is KafkaBindingRebalanceListener interface that you can use

```
@Slf4j
@Component
public class KafkaRebalanceListener implements KafkaBindingRebalanceListener {

    @Value("${config.kafka.topics.offsets:null}")
    private String topicOffsets;

    @Override
    public void onPartitionsAssigned(String bindingName, Consumer<?, ?> consumer, Collection<TopicPartition> partitions, boolean initial) {
        if (topicOffsets != null && initial) {
            final Optional<Map<TopicPartition, Long>> offsetsOptional = parseOffset(topicOffsets);
            if (offsetsOptional.isPresent()) {
                final Map<TopicPartition, Long> offsetsMap = offsetsOptional.get();
                partitions.forEach(tp -> {
                    if (offsetsMap.containsKey(tp)) {
                        final Long offset = offsetsMap.get(tp);
                        try {
                            log.info("Seek topic {} partition {} to offset {}", tp.topic(), tp.partition(), offset);
                            consumer.seek(tp, offset);
                        } catch (Exception e) {
                            log.error("Unable to set offset {} for topic {} and partition {}", offset, tp.topic(), tp.partition());
                        }
                    }
                });
            }
        }
    }

    private Optional<Map<TopicPartition, Long>> parseOffset(String offsetParam) {
        if (offsetParam == null || offsetParam.isEmpty()) {
            return Optional.empty();
        }

        return Optional.of(Arrays.stream(offsetParam.split(","))
                .flatMap(slice -> {
                    String[] items = slice.split("\\|");
                    String topic = items[0];
                    return Arrays.stream(Arrays.copyOfRange(items, 1, items.length))
                            .map(r -> {
                                String[] record = r.split(":");
                                int partition = Integer.parseInt(record[0]);
                                long offset = Long.parseLong(record[1]);
                                return new AbstractMap.SimpleEntry<>(new TopicPartition(topic, partition), offset);
                            });
                }).collect(Collectors.toMap(AbstractMap.SimpleEntry::getKey, AbstractMap.SimpleEntry::getValue)));
    }
}
```

**config.kafka.topics.offsets** field look like this but you can use any format

```
String topicOffsets = "topic2|1:100|2:120|3:140,topic3|1:1000|2:1200|3:1400";
```

Answer (score 1):

If you're talking disaster, what makes you think you can write anything to DB?
In other words you may end up dealing with de-duplication on at least one event (at least you have to account for that) and if so, then de-duplication is still something you have to deal with.

I understand your concern with re-play (you simply don't want to reply from the beginning, but you can store periodic snapshots which would ensure you have a relatively fixed amount of events hat may need to be reprocessed/de-dupped.

That said, Kafka maintains the current offset, so you can rely on natural transaction features of Kafka to ensure that the next time you start your microservice it will begin from the last un-processed (successfully) offset.

Comment: You can use the `resetOffsets` consumer property to reset to the beginning of the topic. You can use the `kafka-consumer-groups` command-line tool to reset consumer partitions to any arbitrary offset. There is currently no support in `...stream` to programmatically reset to some arbitrary offset although you can add the `Consumer` as a parameter to the `@StreamListener` and perform the seeks on it; you can also enable Idle container events to get access to the `Consumer` when there is no activity. Spring Kafka itself does provide other mechanisms but they are not currently exposed by ...stream

Comment: Thanks @GaryRussell, the `kafka-consumer-groups` tool is a useful option for resetting to a specific offset, although I'm surprised it doesn't support resetting to an offset _for a specific partition_ (our topics have many partitions).

Comment: For our purposes, I like the idea of resetting offsets to a specific *datetime*. When restoring a service to a snapshotted database, we could simply reset the offsets to just before the snapshot was taken, to guarantee each message is processed at least once. This way the code is kept as simple as possible as we don't need to commit offsets to a DB or seek to an offset programatically.

Comment: `>I'm surprised it doesn't support resetting to an offset for a specific partition `. Me too; I didn't notice that.